# VSCode does not show missing import in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have just created a new TypeScript project in a new folder. TypeScript is version 4.4.2.

The folder structure is the following

```
- myProject
  -src
   -folder-1
     -file-1.ts
   -folder-2
     -file-2.ts
  -tsconfig.json
```

The files containing the logic are very simple

**file-1.ts**

```
function function_1() {
    console.log('Print something');
}
```

**file-2.ts**

```
function function_2() {
    function_1();
}
```

What I am used to see is that VSCode shows a red error in the only line of function `function_2` since `function_1` is not imported (and not even exported).

On the contrary, VSCode does not show any error. On the contrary with `CTRL+Click` on the line `function-1()` of **file-2.ts**, VSCode opens the actual implementation of `function-1` in **file-1**.

More, if I run `tsc` the compiler does not complain and creates the relevant ***.js** files in the `dist` folder. Naturally if I try to execute `function-2()` I get an error telling me that ***"function_1 is not defined"***.

Here my **tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true
    },
    "include": ["src/*.ts", "src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2016", "dom"]
}
```

One more detail. If I run the command `npm run tsc src/folder-2/file-2.ts` (where `tsc` is the standard npm script to run the TypeScript compiler) I get an error on the console but still the compiler produces **file-2.js** as its output.

I am pretty sure I am missing something silly, but I am not able to see it.